# Pass parameters to ajax function that can be used in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax/jquery snippet, and my goal is to send a request that has a 'type' parameter. I already have a username and password, which I can echo back no problems. However, if I attempt to add a 
`type:'login'` to the data of the request, I can never access 'type' from the php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#button").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
               url: 'login.php',
               type: 'POST',
               content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               data: {type:'login',username:user,password:pass},//this is my issue, why can't I pass type?
               success: function(response){
                    //determine if login was successful
               }
     });
});
```

The login.php simply checks if POST is set and checks for parameter POST["type"], but it does not get passed?

PHP

```
<?php


if (!isset($_POST))
{
    $msg = "NO POST MESSAGE SET, POLITELY **** OFF";
    echo json_encode($msg);
    exit(0);
}
$request = $_POST;
$response = "unsupported request type, politely **** OFF";
switch ($request["type"])
{
    case "login":
        $response = "login, yeah we can do that";
    break;
}
echo json_encode($response);
exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: Your jQuery looks fine, can you add your PHP code to the question?

Comment: Ready not read :)

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: You can use the Network tab of DevTools to see what parameters were sent.

Comment: This is invalid: `content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` If you have `-` in an object key, it needs to be quoted.

Comment: You're obviously not posting the actual code, and the problem could be in something you didn't copy correctly.

Comment: @Barmar at first sight, this looks fine ! Two small js mistakes... php is fine. I don't know if he needs an answer... we already guided him through the comments here.

Comment: You better replace [content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'] by  [headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'          }] and you are good to go :)

Comment: It's not even necessary to specify the content type, `x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just debugging here ! if we were allowed to edit his question... it's  already solved :) It just doesn't make sense to readers !

Comment: Actually, it should be `contentType:`.

Comment: What I suggested is a workaround  for the "Unexpected token '-'"  ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, you need to use jQuery's `$.param` to serialize the value. Check here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/